# Replace specific line in a text file

Tags: matlab, file, text, text-files

I have a text file (for example: data.dat) as shown below, with a number of lines.

```
data.dat

@motion parameters
speed= 22,30,60
range= 600
rotation= 50

@controls
act= 2,3,4,5
```

I want to read it and replace the line that comes right after the line starting with a specfic keyword e.g. "@controls" . In this case, the line to be replaced is this one:

```
act= 2,3,4,5
```

and it should be changed in a loop. For an instant, for example, it would change to:

```
act= 1,0,8,-2
```

I have tried this

```
fullFileName = fullfile(pwd, 'data.dat')
% Open the file.
fileID = fopen(fullFileName, 'rt');
% Read the first line of the file.
textLine = fgetl(fileID);
while ischar(textLine)
  % Read the remaining lines of the file.
    fprintf('%s\n', textLine)
  if startsWith(textLine,'@controls')
    % Line starts with @controls, so change values
      textLine = fgetl(fileID); % Step one line below
      textLine = 'act= %4.1f,%4.1f,%4.1f,%4.1f\n ';
     fprintf(fileID,textLine,act_1,act_2,act_3,act_4);

  end
  % Read the next line.
    textLine = fgetl(fileID);
end
% All done reading all lines, so close the file.
fclose(fileID);
```

But this just deletes the original line!

I'd appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tired?

Comment: Check my edit..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I just figured it out.**

```
fid = fopen('data.dat','r');        % Open File to read
replaceline = 'act= 1,0,8,-2';      % Line to replace
i = 1;
tline = 's';
A = {[]};
while ischar(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'@controls')) % find '@controls'
        A{i}=tline;
        A{i+1} = replaceline;               % replace line
        tline = fgetl(fid);
        i = i+1;
    else
        A{i}=tline;
    end
    i = i+1;
end
fclose(fid);
fid2=fopen('data.dat','w');            % Open file to write
for i=1:length(A)-1
    fprintf(fid2,['%s',char([13,10])],A{i});
end
fclose(fid2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bound to this line-by-line approach, one could - for example - also use [`fileread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) and [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to get all the lines of the file, modify them, and finally save them back to file.

This would be my solution:

```matlab
% Read whole content of file as text
C = fileread('data.dat');

% Split at every new line character; Caveat: Windows vs. Unix vs. MacOS
C = regexp(C, '\r\n', 'split').'

% Find line numbers of @controls lines
idx = find(strcmp('@controls', C))

% Replace following lines with desired values
act = [1, 0, 8, -2; 0, 1, 2, 3];
for id = 1:numel(idx)
  C{idx(id)+1} = sprintf('act= %d,%d,%d,%d', act(id, :));  
end
C

% Save file
fid = fopen('data.dat', 'r+');
fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', C{:});
fclose(fid);
```

I used a modified `data.dat` like this:

```
@motion parameters
speed= 22,30,60
range= 600
rotation= 50

@controls
act= 2,3,4,5

@controls
act= 2,3,4,5
```

After executing the above script, the result looks like this:

```
@motion parameters
speed= 22,30,60
range= 600
rotation= 50

@controls
act= 1,0,8,-2

@controls
act= 0,1,2,3
```

In your question, you described the desired output as:

```
act= 1,0,8,-2
```

But, in your code you have

```
textLine = 'act= %4.1f,%4.1f,%4.1f,%4.1f\n ';
```

So, please adapt the format specifier according to your actual needs, if necessary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I was wondering what edit I can make to compare the string (@controls) with just the first string with equal length (if existed) in each line, and not with the whole line since strcmp('@controls', C) compares (@controls) with each line as whole.